# How to create Google blogger type Sub Domain URL for blog

Tags: asp.net

I have to create a BLOG section in my website. If my site is www.abc.com, then I have to create different blogs like  google blogger service.

http://author1.abc.com

http://author2.abc.com

I have the ability to create unlimited sub domains but I am not able to understand how above blog URL will work. These will be virtual sub domains or will I have to create actual sub domains.
Is it possible via Url rewriting? If yes, how?

If I use Url rewriting, browser will redirect the above URL to page for which I have craeted the URL rewriting rule. I dont want to change the URL in browser.

Any one has any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create actual sub domains for this one and I don't think this can be achieved by URL Rewriting